# How to fix FieldError at /?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been trying to get my categories set up for a blog, I've tried deleting the "migrations" directory and db.sqlite3 to recreate my models and now I am receiving a FieldError.

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'categories' into field. Choices are: category, category_id, comment_count, comments, content, featured, id, overview, post_img, slug, timestamp, title
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from tinymce import HTMLField
from django.utils import timezone

class CategoryTag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('category')
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField('Content')
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_img = models.ImageField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('CategoryTag', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })
```

**Views.py**

```
def get_category_count():
    queryset = Post  \
        .objects  \
        .values('categories__title')  \
        .annotate(Count('categories__title'))  
    return queryset

def index(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[0:3]
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 6)
    page_request_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try: 
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email
        new_signup.save()

    context = {
        'object_list': featured,
        'queryset': paginated_queryset,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def blog_single(request):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html', {})

def category(request):
    return render(request, 'category.html', {})

def post(request, id):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    latest = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'latest': latest,
        'category_count': category_count
    }
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html', context)
```

**Traceback**

Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1420, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'categories' into field. Choices are: category, category_id, comment_count, comments, content, featured, id, overview, 
post_img, slug, timestamp, title

Comment: Please show the full traceback and the view that handles `/`.

Comment: you are using `categories` somewhere in your Html file or view. change that to `category`

Comment: Please share the related view and traceback. Likely you fitered on `categories`, but it should be `category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in view. py you are using `categories` for query_set lookup field that isn't field name. change first view. py code by this part:

```
def get_category_count():
    queryset = Post  \
        .objects  \
        .values('category__title')  \ # here should be category not categories
        .annotate(Count('category__title'))  # here too
    return queryset
```